# How to include a condition into a combined JSP and JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, conditional-statements

Now I have 2 following JavaScript functions :

```
function clearBillingCache(){
    window.location = "billingSearchClear.html"
}

function clearBillingCache_1(){
<%
    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);
%>
}
```

How to have a combined function, so only when request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null
do the following :

```
<%
  request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
  request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);
%>
window.location = "billingSearchClear.html"
```

otherwise do nothing.

Edit :

Thanks Bhaskara !

But actually it's more than what I showed, it might get into an infinite loop, because there is a redirect in :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/billingSearchClear.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String clearCache(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String returnVal = "redirect:/billingSearch.html";

    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);

    return returnVal;
}
```

And I'm calling `clearBillingCache()` in `<body onload=...>`

Comment: Frank, i updated my answer after your new edit. My understanding is User clicks on a link, then you check if there is a session attribute, if there is session attribute u remove it and send the user to /billingSearch.html. Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the code:

```
   function clearBillingCache_1(){
<%
    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);
%>
```

}

will be rendered as

```
function clearBillingCache_1(){

    }
```

You can check this by doing a "View Source" in your browser. Which means the session attributes defined in the scriptlets will anyway be set irrespective of the condition. I personally recommend you not to use the Scriptlets. You can use JSTL to do this. The idea is to use  for conditional check and  for setting the attributes and a Javascript code just to redirect. 
JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${stickyCarrier != null}">
            <c:set var="stickyCarrier" value="null" scope="session"  />
            <c:set var="stickyAgency" value="null" scope="session"  />

        </c:if>
```

and then your javascript:

```
function clearBillingCache(){
    window.location = "billingSearchClear.html"
}
```

Edit:

Ok Frank. So there is some more change required. You are being redirected from a controller/servlet. Please follow the below steps:

- Change your controller code to this:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/search.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String clearCache(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String returnVal = "redirect:/billingSearch.html";
  if(request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null)
  {
      request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyCarrier", null);
      request.getSession().setAttribute("stickyAgency", null);    
  }
  return returnVal;
  ```
- Remove the javascript functions : `clearBillingCache_1()` and
  `clearBillingCache()`
- Remove body onload call on the html